# Raspberry Pi Edimax Wlan Stick drops connection

Tags: wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I finally got the Edimax RTL8188CUS wireless stick of my Raspberry Pi working but I keep losing the connection after just a few minutes.
I can prevent this from happening when I constantly ping the Raspberry Pi. The Pi itself seems to have no outgoing connection problems but I can't access it from my PC if I don't keep the connection busy.
If I lose the connection at the moment I ping my PC from the Raspberry Pi the Pi gets accessible again in both directions.

The Raspberry Pi gets 1A power and besides the wlan stick it controls a 2 port relay. The OS is Raspbian with Xbmc prebuilt by Michael Gorven. No problems when using ethernet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I close this now as "unsolved" because I think it could be a hardware issue of my RPi. Possible that the Raspberry Pi Hardware (or at least USB Ports) suffered during my last project and don't get enough power.
I thought it can't be a hardware issue because constantly pinging helps but 2 people here bet against :)

Answer (score 0):

If constantly pinging helps, it may be a power management issue. Check that it is disabled for the driver:

`cat /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf`

Mine says `options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0`

The file name may vary, any `*.conf` file in that directory will work.

If you are using the RPi as an access point, you should read
http://jenssegers.be/blog/43/Realtek-RTL8188-based-access-point-on-Raspberry-Pi

Comment: Mine says the same. I already tried that but I often read that this hint helped, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a power management issue just like Silpion already posted in his answer.

However: The issue might actually be on the PC side of the connection (I presume its running Windows?).

Check the network card driver in Device Manager. If there is a Power Management tab there disable the setting "Windows is allowed to suspend this device to save power" (or a similar entry, I can't exactly remember the text and I'm not on a Windows system right now).

In general: This is the first thing to look for if a Windows computer as intermittent connectivity issues.

P.S.
If there is no such setting in the Device Manager then the device doesn't support power management in the first place. In that case the problem can't be caused by power management on the Windows side.

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I'm pretty sure that wasn't the issue because I used my laptop often and never had any other wlan problems.

Comment: @yourmother You mean you never noticed before. Doesn't mean it isn't happening. In most cases you won't notice it. It's just that it can cause issues in specific circumstances.